# How to pass array as bind variable to Rails/ActiveRecord raw SQL queries?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I need to pass an array of ids into my raw sql query like this:

```
select offers.* from offers where id in (1,2,3,4,5)
```

The real query includes a lot of joins and aggregation functions and can't be written using Arel expressions or ActiveRecord model methods like `Offer.where(id: [...])`. I'm looking exactly for how to use bind variables in raw queries.

Instead of interpolating ids into string I want to use bind variables like this (pseudo-code):

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all("select offers.* from offers where id in (:ids)", {ids: [1,2,3,4,5]})
```

However, I can't find any solution to perform this. From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50276261/using-oracle-bind-variables-with-select-all-in-rails) ticket I've got a comment with related test-case in ActiveRecord code with the [following](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/127509c071b4f983f2beafc8766e990670a21215/activerecord/test/cases/bind_parameter_test.rb#L42) example:

```
sub   = Arel::Nodes::BindParam.new
binds = [Relation::QueryAttribute.new("id", 1, Type::Value.new)]
sql   = "select * from topics where id = #{sub.to_sql}"

@connection.exec_query(sql, "SQL", binds)
```

I've tried this approach, but it didn't worked at all, my "?" was not replaced by actual values.

I'm using Rails 5.1.6 and MariaDB database.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in a much simpler fashion purely with `arel`. (Also it makes the code far more maintainable than SQL strings)

```
offers = Arel::Table.new('offers') 
ids = [1,2,3,4,5]
query = offers.project(Arel.star).where(offers[:id].in(ids))
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query(query.to_sql)
```

This will result in the following SQL

```
SELECT 
  [offers].*
FROM 
  [offers]
WHERE 
  [offers].[id] IN (1,2,3,4,5)
```

When executed you will receive an `ActiveRecord::Result` object with is usually easiest to deal with by calling `to_hash` and each resulting row will be turned into a `Hash` of `{column_name => value}`

However if you are using rails and `Offer` is a true model then:

```
Offer.where(id: ids)
```

Will result in the same query and will return an `ActiveRecord::Relation` collection of `Offer` objects which is generally more preferable.

**Update**

Seems like you need to enable `prepared_statements` in mysql2 (`mariadb`) in order to use the bind params, which can be done like this:

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  prepared_statements: true  # <- here we go!
```

Please note the following pieces of code: 
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-1-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb#L115

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-1-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb#L40

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-1-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb#L630

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-1-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql/database_statements.rb#L30

As you can see in the last code `exec_query` ignores `bind_params` if `prepared_statements` is turned off (which appears to be the default for the `mysql2` adapter).

Comment: I've used single table for simplicity. The real query is much complex and includes a couple of joins and a log of aggregation functions. I can't use arel or model query methods here.

Comment: @VladimirRozhkov if you can write a valid query you can use `arel` to build it. I have `arel` built queries that translate into 500 lines of SQL using tens of CTEs and joins. `arel` can build anything SQL can handle. If you explain the situation more then I could try and assist

Comment: I'm not looking for solution to my specific case. I'm looking for how to use bind variables in raw queries. This task can be easily done in other ORM's, why ActiveRecord should be different?

Comment: It works with single value but didn't work with arrays.

Comment: "You could do this in a much simpler fashion purely with arel" ... except that query builders are often a lot more obtuse than the corresponding SQL, like in the OP's actual described use case or even something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/30924648/4747937 . Being able to build any SQL query makes `arel` powerful, but it doesn't mean it's simpler.

Comment: @kevlarr I disagree that in this case the arel is more obtuse (verbose?). Additionally IMO, and experience, query assemblers make for a far more composable, maintainable, and portable codebase. What is "simpler" should be not be seen as a short term goal, the simplest code is something that can be extended, altered, reused, and repurposed in the future with minimal effort (even if that requires more effort upfront)

Comment: @engineersmnky In your example, sure - the arel code is simple and clean and quick to understand. I would agree it's maintainable. But a query builder's ability to be 'maintainable' breaks down pretty quickly in more complicated queries, because there tends to be much higher cognitive overhead than just the plain SQL and maintainability depends on developers (yourself, future others, etc) being able to know the deepest ins and outs of query builders _in addition to_ underlying SQL. Can you honestly look at the example I linked and say the arel code is more maintainable than much simpler SQL?

Comment: @kevlarr yes I can say that. Not the way it was designed in the answer but if this was isolated into a formal object and the logical components were separated appropriately it would be far more maintainable than a RAW SQL String. Alternate [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70976225/arel-i-get-stack-level-too-deep-error-when-i-try-to-get-sql-from-arel/70992158#70992158) which I would say is way more maintainable then the desired SQL

Comment: @engineersmnky We've hit the "ideological differences" bedrock, so I'll drop it.