# Arel: I get "stack level too deep" error when I try to get SQL from Arel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arel

First I'd like to describe idea of what I am trying to do. I have "jobstat_jobs" table where I store the information about computing job perfomance. I am trying to compose 2 queries: 1) jobs grouped by project 2) jobs grouped by project and state. Then these queries are inner joined and I want to display share of jobs of each state among all jobs. I implemented it using ActiveRecord and raw sql, but I can't do it with arel.  I get the "stack level too deep" on the "joined.to_sql" line.

```
      members = Core::Member.arel_table
      jobs = Perf::Job.arel_table
      cool_relation = jobs.where(jobs[:state].not_in(%w[COMPLETETED RUNNING unknown]))
      relation = cool_relation.join( Arel::Nodes::SqlLiteral.new <<-SQL
              INNER JOIN core_members ON core_members.login = jobstat_jobs.login
      SQL
      ).join(Arel::Nodes::SqlLiteral.new <<-SQL
          RIGHT JOIN sessions_projects_in_sessions ON
          sessions_projects_in_sessions.project_id = core_members.project_id
        SQL
      ).group(members[:project_id]).project(members[:project_id].as('id'))

      hours = '(extract(epoch from (end_time - start_time))/ 3600)'
      selections = {
        node_hours: "(sum((#{hours})*num_nodes))",
        jobs: "count(jobstat_jobs.id)"
      }
      selections.each do |key, value|
        relation = relation.project(
          Arel::Nodes::SqlLiteral.new(value).as(key.to_s)
        )
      end
      state_relation = relation.project(jobs[:state].as('state'))
                               .group(jobs[:state])
      s = state_relation.as('s')
      pp ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query(state_relation.to_sql).to_a
      joined = relation.join(s)
                       .on(jobs[:id].eq(s[:id]))
                       .project(s[:id], s[:state])
      puts joined.to_sql
      joined
```

I noticed the strange thing. When I replace "joined = relation" with "jobs.where(jobs[:state].not_in(%w[COMPLETETED RUNNING unknown]))" it works. But when I replace "joined = relation" with "joined = cool_relation" it doesn't work and I get "stack level too deep" (these 2 replacements are almost the same).

Arel v 9.0.0, Postgresql

Comment: Can you provide the desired SQL? Also parts of this post are confusing: 1) I don't see start_date and finish_date used anywhere; 2) what is the hash after `hours` it just seems like noise; 3) what are selections as this variable assignment is not shown (maybe it is supposed to be the hash?)

Comment: I fixed these errors. That happened because I tried to isolate all my code inside only one method, but I forgot some parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that I understand the desired output here is how I would go about this

```
class Report

  JOB_STATS = Arel::Table.new('jobstat_jobs')
  CORE_MEMBERS = Arel::Table.new('core_members')
  SESSIONS = Arel::Table.new('sessions_projects_in_sessions')

  def additions
    # This could be ported too if I knew the tables for end_time, start_time, and num_nodes
    {
      node_hours: Arel.sql("((extract(epoch from (end_time - start_time))/ 3600))*num_nodes").sum,
      jobs: JOB_STATS[:id].count
    }
  end 
  
  def n
    @n ||= _base_query.as('n')
  end 

  def s 
    @s ||= _base_query
            .project(JOB_STATS[:state])
            .group(JOB_STATS[:state]).as('s')
  end 

  def alias_columns 
    additions.keys.flat_map do |key|
      [s[key].as("s_#{key}"), 
       n[key].as("n_#{key}"),
       (s[key] / n[key]).as("share_#{key}")]
    end 
  end

  def query 
    Arel::SelectManager.new.project(
           s[:project_id].as('id'), 
           s[:state],
           *alias_columns 
         )
         .from(s)
         .join(n).on(s[:project_id].eq(n[:project_id]))
  end 

  def to_sql
    query.to_sql 
  end 

  private
    def cast_as_decimal(value,alias_name:)
      Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new(
        "CAST",
        [Arel::Nodes::As.new(value, Arel.sql('DECIMAL'))]
      ).as(alias_name.to_s)
    end 
    def _base_query
      JOB_STATS
        .project(
          CORE_MEMBERS[:project_id],
          *additions.map {|k,v| cast_as_decimal(v, alias_name: k)})
        .join(CORE_MEMBERS).on(CORE_MEMBERS[:login].eq(JOB_STATS[:login]))
        .outer_join(SESSIONS).on(SESSIONS[:project_id].eq(CORE_MEMBERS[:project_id]))
        .where(JOB_STATS[:state].not_in(['COMPLETETED', 'RUNNING', 'unknown']))
        .group(CORE_MEMBERS[:project_id])
    end 
end
```

Result of `Report.new.to_sql`

```
SELECT 
  s."project_id" AS id, 
  s."state", 
  s."node_hours" AS s_node_hours, 
  n."node_hours" AS n_node_hours, 
  s."node_hours" / n."node_hours" AS share_node_hours, 
  s."jobs" AS s_jobs, 
  n."jobs" AS n_jobs, 
  s."jobs" / n."jobs" AS share_jobs 
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    "core_members"."project_id", 
    CAST(SUM(((extract(epoch from (end_time - start_time))/ 3600))*num_nodes) AS DECIMAL) AS node_hours, 
    CAST(COUNT("jobstat_jobs"."id") AS DECIMAL) AS jobs, 
    "jobstat_jobs"."state" 
  FROM 
    "jobstat_jobs" 
    INNER JOIN "core_members" ON "core_members"."login" = "jobstat_jobs"."login" 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN "sessions_projects_in_sessions" ON "sessions_projects_in_sessions"."project_id" = "core_members"."project_id" 
  WHERE 
    "jobstat_jobs"."state" NOT IN (N'COMPLETETED', N'RUNNING', N'unknown') 
  GROUP BY 
    "core_members"."project_id", 
    "jobstat_jobs"."state"
) s 
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT 
    "core_members"."project_id", 
    CAST(SUM(((extract(epoch from (end_time - start_time))/ 3600))*num_nodes) AS DECIMAL) AS node_hours, 
    CAST(COUNT("jobstat_jobs"."id") AS DECIMAL) AS jobs 
  FROM 
    "jobstat_jobs" 
    INNER JOIN "core_members" ON "core_members"."login" = "jobstat_jobs"."login" 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN "sessions_projects_in_sessions" ON "sessions_projects_in_sessions"."project_id" = "core_members"."project_id" 
  WHERE 
    "jobstat_jobs"."state" NOT IN (N'COMPLETETED', N'RUNNING', N'unknown') 
  GROUP BY 
    "core_members"."project_id"
) n ON s."project_id" = n."project_id"
```

This will also allow you further filter the resulting query like so:

```
rpt = Report.new 
q = rpt.query.where(rpt.n[:jobs].gt(12))
q.to_sql 
#=> "...same as above...WHERE n.\"jobs\" > 12"
```

Comment: Nicely done:) I should have avoided SQL string in inner joins, because it looked bad obviously and in fact I refactored this aspect in parallel with you. But still I don't like arel named functions, in this case pure SQL is more readable for me or ordinary Rails newbies. But your output SQL is formatted  much better and large functions are avoided)

Comment: @SwipeZ in your specific instance I can agree because you control the definition of all the variables but in general I avoid raw SQL becaus if in the future these arguments were not as contained using `NamedFunction` they will be escaped preventing any injectability. Also casting happens so often I am not sure why it has not been assimilated into Arel yet (maybe I will get around to making a pull request someday)

Answer (score 1):

My problem is that I expected arel to create a new object each time I chain method(like ActiveRecord::Relation).
Just add #clone method here:

```
joined = relation.clone.join(s)
                       .on(jobs[:id].eq(s[:id]))
                       .project(s[:id], s[:state])
```

I got  SQL string, but it was wrong and there were exceptions on database level. Now my code is following:

```
      members = Core::Member.arel_table
      jobs = Perf::Job.arel_table
      cool_relation = jobs.where(jobs[:state].not_in(%w[COMPLETETED RUNNING unknown]))
      relation = cool_relation.join( Arel::Nodes::SqlLiteral.new <<-SQL
              INNER JOIN core_members ON core_members.login = jobstat_jobs.login
      SQL
      .gsub("\n", ' ')).join(Arel::Nodes::SqlLiteral.new <<-SQL
          RIGHT JOIN sessions_projects_in_sessions ON
          sessions_projects_in_sessions.project_id = core_members.project_id
        SQL
      .gsub("\n", ' ')).group(members[:project_id]).project(members[:project_id].as('id'))

      hours = '(extract(epoch from (end_time - start_time))/ 3600)'
      selections = {
        node_hours: "(sum((#{hours})*num_nodes))",
        jobs: "count(jobstat_jobs.id)"
      }
      selections.each do |key, value|
        relation = relation.project(
          # Arel::Nodes::SqlLiteral.new(value).as(key.to_s)
          Arel::Nodes::SqlLiteral.new("(CAST(#{value} AS decimal))").as(key.to_s)
        )
      end
      state_relation = relation.clone.project(jobs[:state].as('state'))
                               .group(jobs[:state])
      s = state_relation.as('s')
      n = relation.as('n')
      pp ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query(state_relation.to_sql).to_a
      pp ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query(relation.to_sql).to_a


      manager = Arel::SelectManager.new
      joined = manager.project(s[:id], s[:state])
                      .from(s)
                      .join(n).on(s[:id].eq(n[:id]))

      selections.keys.each do |key|
        joined = joined.project(s[key].as("s_#{key}"), n[key].as("n_#{key}"))
                       .project(s[key] / n[key].as("share_#{key}"))
      end
      puts joined.to_sql
      joined
```

Pay attention to the #clone method used here too. When I remove #clone, project method affects relation variable too and I get wrong SQL because of that.

The joined.to_sql line produces the following and works as expected:

```
SELECT s."id", s."state", s."node_hours" AS s_node_hours, 
n."node_hours" AS n_node_hours, s."node_hours" / n."node_hours" AS
share_node_hours, s."jobs" AS s_jobs, n."jobs" AS n_jobs, 
s."jobs" / n."jobs" AS share_jobs FROM (SELECT "core_members".
"project_id" AS id, (CAST((sum(((extract(epoch from (end_time - start_time))/ 3600))*num_nodes)) AS decimal)) AS node_hours, 
(CAST(count(jobstat_jobs.id) AS decimal)) AS jobs, 
"jobstat_jobs"."state" AS state FROM "jobstat_jobs"   INNER JOIN 
core_members ON core_members.login = jobstat_jobs.login            
RIGHT JOIN sessions_projects_in_sessions ON           sessions_projects_in_sessions.project_id = core_members.project_id  
WHERE "jobstat_jobs"."state" NOT IN ('COMPLETETED', 'RUNNING', 'unknown') 
GROUP BY "core_members"."project_id", "jobstat_jobs"."state") s INNER JOIN 
(SELECT "core_members"."project_id" AS id, (CAST((sum(((extract(epoch from 
(end_time - start_time))/ 3600))*num_nodes)) AS decimal)) AS node_hours, 
(CAST(count(jobstat_jobs.id) AS decimal)) AS jobs FROM "jobstat_jobs"     
          INNER JOIN core_members ON core_members.login = jobstat_jobs.login            RIGHT JOIN sessions_projects_in_sessions ON           
sessions_projects_in_sessions.project_id = core_members.project_id  WHERE
 "jobstat_jobs"."state" NOT IN ('COMPLETETED', 'RUNNING', 'unknown') GROUP BY
 "core_members"."project_id") n ON s."id" = n."id"
```